# Return a subplot from a function

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython

Using Matplotlib in an IPython Notebook, I would like to create a figure with subplots which are returned from a function:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib inline

def create_subplot(data):
    more_data = do_something_on_data()  
    bp = plt.boxplot(more_data)
    # return boxplot?
    return bp

# make figure with subplots
f, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharey=True, figsize=(10,5))

ax1 -> how can I get the plot from create_subplot() and put it on ax1?
ax1 -> how can I get the plot from create_subplot() and put it on ax2?
```

I know that I can directly add a plot to an axis:

```
ax1.boxplot(data)
```

But how can I return a plot from a function and use it as a subplot?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Typically, you'd do something like this:

```
def create_subplot(data, ax=None):
    if ax is None:
        ax = plt.gca()
    more_data = do_something_on_data()  
    bp = ax.boxplot(more_data)
    return bp

# make figure with subplots
f, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharey=True, figsize=(10,5))
create_subplot(data, ax1)
```

You don't "return a plot from a function and use it as a subplot". Instead you need to plot the boxplot *on* the axes in the subplot.

The `if ax is None` portion is just there so that passing in an explicit axes is optional (if not, the current pyplot axes will be used, identical to calling `plt.boxplot`.).  If you'd prefer, you can leave it out and require that a specific axes be specified.

Comment: Great, that works! The 'nature' of the figure and axes objects and the logic behind the plotting commands can be difficult to understand at the beginning.

Comment: "Instead you need to plot the boxplot on the axes in the subplot." This is what I needed to make my mental shift. Thanks