# How to return a subplot graph from a function?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, visualization

I created a function that takes some inputs and creates a graph out of it. And now I want to return that subplot graph from the function which can be plotted later or used on the web page.

My function looks something like this (just a dummy representation)

```py
def plot_g(x, y):
    # subplots
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(18, 14))
    
    # bar
    sns.barplot(x, y, ax= ax[0][0]
    
    # pie
    ax[0][1].pie(x,y)
```

I don't know what and how to do it, I also tried to follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20073017/return-a-subplot-from-a-function), but I am not able to understand and apply that here.

Comment: More flexible is to pass the ax to the function rather than create one

Comment: Please explain exactly what do you want to do with the figure later.

Comment: You write *"I want to return that subplot graph from the function which can be plotted later"*. Well, matplotlib doesn't work that way.  You need to call the function at the moment you want to plot, not earlier.  As mentioned by Jody Klymak, the recommended way to do so, passes the `ax` as  a parameter to the function.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply return ax and fig:

```
def plot_g(x, y):
    # subplots
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(18, 14))
    
    # bar
    sns.barplot(x, y, ax= ax[0][0]
    
    # pie
    ax[0][1].pie(x,y)
     
    return fig, ax
```

or return just `ax` with `return ax`.

Then you can use `ax` as needed.

```
axs=plot_g(x, y)
axs[0][0].set_xlabel("Changed x Label")
```

Comment: now after getting `axs `  how can I plot all graphs that are subplots. I am kind of trying to get it stored in a variable, which I call whenever I want to plot my all graph.